# Cannot authenticate $http with passport Basic Auth

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

How can I make my $http call with passport basic auth?

I setup basic auth with passport on my server, and I can use POSTMAN to test. But when I try to do it on my angular application I cannot get it to pass the username and password for the basic auth.

I have the following on my $http call

```
$http({
    method:'POST',
    url: 'http://myapicall.com/api/login',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization' : 'Basic Username:MySecret'
    },....
```

Do I need to add anything else? I keep getting not authorized and when I use the same username and password on postman it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `btoa` function to convert your `username:password` to `base64`

```
$http({
    method:'POST',
    url: 'http://myapicall.com/api/login',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + window.btoa('Username:MySecret')
    },....
```

Or use this library https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64

Comment: I did add that not sure why. I also dumped the $window.btoa('username:password') and it does match the postman header.

Comment: Could it be because I'm on local host and trying to access my API? I do have the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" So I can access from my local host.

Comment: Show headers of server response, please. Is it with status `401`? Does it has `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="myRealm"` header?

Comment: This is what I get on the server response. Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:12
Date:Sun, 13 Mar 2016 18:06:35 GMT
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Users"
X-Powered-By:Express

Comment: Here is what I have on my express and passport code.

`var passport = require('passport');
var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
....
app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(function(username,password,done){
//CHECK FOR THE API ACCESS
//IT VALIDATES THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD
});
...
app.use('/api',passport.authenticate('basic',{session:false}),routesApi);
`